# How to get the displayed value from a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

i've got a problem i don't know how do solve it.
On my web page i load a table dynamically (and only the user want to) from an other apex application with:

```
function getParameter (filter){
  var url;
  var html;
  filter = filter.replace(/ /g,'%20')
  url = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:8080/apex/f?p=PAR_PARAMETER:1:'+APP_SESSION+
    ':IR_REPORT_Query_Parameter::RIR,CIR:IR_P_SYS.SZGETTEXT(T.EZS_NO):'+filter;
 html = $('#ParameterSettings').load(url +' .apexir_WORKSHEET_DATA');
```

}

this works fine.

My problem now is that the user can choose between: I want to edit the values, in this case the **value col** (display only) will be replaced with:

```
'<input type="text" value="|HTML|" size="30" maxlength="4000" class="P3_PARAMETER_VALUES">'
```

This also works fine, but how can i get the values that the user can now enter into the input field?

The table bevor it is editable:

```
<div id="P3_PARAMETERSETTING">
<table>
 <thead></thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
   <tr class="even">
    <td headers="LINK">
    <td align="left" headers="P_SYS.SZGETTEXT(T.EZS_NO)">(Dist) Driving time</td>
    <td align="left" headers="NAME">REQ.data.source.trip</td>
    <td align="left" headers="Value">tadaaa</td>
    <td align="left" headers="Default">0</td>
    <td align="left" headers="P_SYS.SZGETTEXT(D.EZS_NO)">Data source for trips to use         in the query: 0 = all, 1 = online recorded data, 2 = vehicle recorded data</td>
    <td align="left" headers="Max">2</td>
    <td align="left" headers="Min">0</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

after switch to editable:

```
<div id="P3_PARAMETERSETTING">
<table>
 <thead></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="odd">
   <td headers="LINK">
   <td align="left" headers="P_SYS.SZGETTEXT(T.EZS_NO)">(Dist) Driving time</td>
   <td align="left" headers="NAME">REQ.grid.value.size</td>
   <td align="left" headers="Value">
    <input class="P3_PARAMETER_VALUES" type="text" maxlength="4000" size="30" value="tadaaa">
   </td>
   <td align="left" headers="Default">60</td>
   <td align="left" headers="P_SYS.SZGETTEXT(D.EZS_NO)">Default data query value grid size</td>
   <td align="left" headers="Max">43200</td>
   <td align="left" headers="Min">10</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

thanks
mario

if any one need more code just leave a comment.

Comment: Could you clarify more what your problem is? what do you want to do with those two tables you posted?

Comment: mhm i thought i worte it. anyway... this two tables are the same ? i just make the value col editable via jquery, this works fine. After i made the col editable i got a problem to get the edited values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to alter the HTML, then the simplest answer would be to ensure you add a unique id to each new input element.

```
<input id="VALUE_1" class="P3_PARAMETER_VALUES" type="text" maxlength="4000" size="30" value="tadaaa">
```

Then you can access with normal JavaScript

```
var value1 = document.getElementById('VALUE_1').value;
```

You could make this sort of selection more powerful by using a JavaScript library like jQuery:

http://jquery.com/

You may also want to look into contenteditable:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable